# sapling add on tree

Tags: sapling-addon

i would like to know how I reappear the sapling add tree menu, I made a tree but I want to modify it, but I can't find the menu anymore how do I make it appear again so I edit the tree

Comment: As with most objects in Blender, it's not possible to modify their original shape once you've carried out any other action. If you've just clicked on the 3D view and the menu disappeared you can bring it back with F9, but for instance moving the tree will mean that you can't bring the menu back.

Comment: thanks my brother

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann All true of course but as I said you can't bring back the menu to modify the original. Regarding your last sentences, **If** you remember, you can of course save your original settings as a preset at the bottom of the menu and then reload them after adding a new tree object, but that's not quite the same thing! :^)

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann I wasn't disagreeing so I think we should leave it at that!